# Reading an CSV file using JSTL: csvJDBC

Tags: jsp, csv, netbeans, jstl

I need to read an CSV file into a JSP using JSTL.

I tried using csvJDBC but could not find enough documentation about how to access the file.

[CSVJDBC](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)

I am creating the project in Netbeans and am unsure of where exactly should I place the file and access it.

The sample code they have given is:

> Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver"); Connection conn =
>   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:" + args[0]);

Can anyone please help me interpret this and suggest the location I should put my CSV file in the case.

In the worst case, if you know of any other alternative to achieve the same, even that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the Apache Commons whenever able, for this kind of stuff:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

And they have some simple examples here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html